# Adding GeoPackage data (covering whole country) to specific area of the country in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, geopackage, extract, building

I have a big GeoPackage of building data for a whole country. I want to add only building data for a certain part of the country. I have tried adding the whole data package and then "select by location" but it keeps crashing, (too big), any ideas?

Comment: Does the dataset have attributes that you could filter by to a specific location/area?

Comment: if you dont have this info on the attribute table, try join attributes by location tool. Another approach would be field calculator overlay function